# Can't center navigation in div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, menubar

Hi im working on a responsive website. Right now I have a problem with my navigation which i can't center in my div. Also I have a problem with my dropdown menu which destroy the otder when my navigation starts to fit the div.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

        <title>Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="body_wrapper">
                <div id="header_wrapper" class="clearfix">
                    <div id="header_content" class="content_container">
                        <div id="language_wrapper">

                            <div class="language active">
                                <span>Deutsch</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="language">
                                <a href="#">
                                <span>Englisch</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="hLogo_wrapper">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="images/starbucks.png">
                            </a>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
                <div id="inner_content" class="content_container">
                    <div class="mainMenu clearfix" >
                        <ul class="clearfix">
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Aktuelles</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Speisekarte ￬</a>
                                <ul class="hidden">
                                    <li><a href="#">Mittagstisch</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Frühstück</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Reservierung</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Gallerie</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div id="footer_wrapper"></div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

and here is my css file so far

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
img {border: 0;}

.clearfix:after{
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;  
}


.content_container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 62.5%;
}

#inner_content{
}


#header_wrapper{
    height: 220px;
    background: url('images/header.png');


}

#hLogo_wrapper img{
    max-width: 100%;

}


#language_wrapper{
    float: right;
}
#language_wrapper .language{
    display: inline;
}

#hLogo_wrapper{
    float: left;
}
.mainMenu{
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.mainMenu ul {
    position: relative;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    left: 10%;

}


.mainMenu li {
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
}

.mainMenu li a {
    display:inline-block;
    min-width:140px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background: #2f3036;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.mainMenu li:hover a {
    background: #19c589;
}


.mainMenu li:hover ul a {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    color: #2f3036;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    z-index: 120;

}

/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
.mainMenu li:hover ul a:hover {
    background: #19c589;
    color: #fff;
}

.mainMenu li ul {
    display: none;
}


.mainMenu li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}


.mainMenu li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 140px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}


.mainMenu ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Wht do you mean by *destroy the otder when my navigation starts to fit thae div.*..? can you be more specific..? if possible please add a simple demo in something like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or an image..?

Answer (score 0):

You have left marked at 10% on your menu ul which is causing your drop down content to become off-centered.

```
.mainMenu ul {
position: relative;
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
left: 10%;
```

Changing left to 0; will straighten this out.

```
.mainMenu ul {
position: relative;
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
left: 0;
```